# Using Bootstrap DatePicker in Rails scaffold form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datepicker

I've got an auto-generated form from a scaffold model, and in the new.html.erb I can't add the DatePicker option to my date field (**effective-date**). Scaffold doesn't generate the form fields; it has just:

app/view/documents/new.html.erb:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= render 'form', document: @document %>
        ** no fields here to customize **
    </div>
    <input type="text" id="TestDate" data-provide='datepicker' >
</div>
```

Model:

```
create_table "documents", force: true do |t|
    t.string    "docname"
    t.string    "description"
    t.string    "doctype"
    t.boolean   "renewal"
    t.date      "effective_date"
    t.date      "expiration_date"
    t.timestamp "created_at"
    t.timestamp "updated_at"
  end
```

TestDate does work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The  whole form and the fields are in the `app/view/documents/_form.html.erb` file

Comment: Ah, yes! "render 'form'" refers to the partial named _form.html. I add the code below and it worked!! Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comment above I added my line of code in documents/_form.html.erb thusly:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :effectiveDate %>
     <input type="text" name="effectiveDate" id="effectiveDate" data-provide='datepicker'
  </div>
```

I took out the line that defined effectiveDate and replaced it with the datepicker line.

Answer (score 1):

Hi have you properly followed the steps?
Follow the [documentation](https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-datepicker-rails).
Or more precisely follow these steps:

1 Include bootstrap-datepicker-rails in Gemfile;

```
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
```

2 Add this line to app/assets/stylesheets/application.css

```
 *= require bootstrap-datepicker
 # Or if using bootstrap v3:
 *= require bootstrap-datepicker3
```

3 Add this line to app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
```

4 Use it like this

```
<input type="text" data-provide='datepicker>
```